# dynamic height and width of canvas based on selected images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I am trying to have a canvas image drawn based on the selected image

```
<canvas id="canvas" ></canvas>
<input type="file" id="file-input">
```

Javascript

```
$(function() {
    $('#file-input').change(function(e) {
        var file = e.target.files[0],
            imageType = /image.*/;

        if (!file.type.match(imageType))
            return;

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = fileOnload;
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);

    });

    function fileOnload(e) {
        var $img = $('<img>', { src: e.target.result });
        var canvas = $('#canvas')[0];
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        $img.load(function() {
            context.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
        });
    }
});
```

This writes the file to canvas, but the problem i face is,  its writing the image only till the height and width of canvas.

How can i have the canvas width height automatically set to the height and width of the image selected

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RsxtG/191/)

Also the image that is being drawn is very huge compared to the original image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I don't have enough points, I can't comment on previous answer.

You should update the height & width of canvas dom element.

```
var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
$img.load(function() {
        canvas.width  = this.width;
        canvas.height = this.height;
        context.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
});
```

Working Demo: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RsxtG/195/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
$('#file-input').change(function(e) {
    var file = e.target.files[0],
        imageType = /image.*/;

    if (!file.type.match(imageType))
        return;

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = fileOnload;
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);

});

function fileOnload(e) {
    var $img = $('<img>', { src: e.target.result });
    var canvas = $('#canvas')[0];
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    $img.load(function() {
        canvas.width  = this.width;
        canvas.height = this.height;
        context.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
    });
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to get dimensions (`width` and `height`) of the image once it loaded and set dimensions of the canvas to their values:

```
    $img.load(function() {
        canvas.width = this.width;
        canvas.height = this.height;
        context.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
    });
```

Comment: @vignesh `$img` in your code is a jQuery object, so it needed to be converted to DOM element. See updated answer

Comment: Yes Sir I made that change in the fiddle link i have commented. Not sure why its not working

Comment: there are lot of size differences when i try png images

Comment: @vignesh I don't see appropriate changes in your fiddle. See the needed changes in my [fork](http://jsfiddle.net/h21L9007/)